# Python 2.7 IDLE not opening.More in description

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

Windows 7 32 bit 
command line is working fine.
Tried deleting .idlec files in C:/Myaccount

when opening through CMD i get this

> .(some other stuff) . .  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py",
>   line 385, in handle_EOF    raise EOFError EOFError

Please help

Comment: IDLE maintainer here.  I have never seen this error or a report thereof.  I presume the error message appeared on Command Prompt.  What *exactly* did you type to start IDLE.  Did the message appear immediately, before you interacted with IDLE?  If not, what did you do (be as exact as possible) to cause its appearance?

Comment: The docstring for rpc baseclass `handle_EOF` says "action taken upon link being closed by peer".  Please post the entire traceback, formatted as code (to keep the line formatting intact).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall the shell from the python website? Essentially redownload the installer, install again to same directory ?

Also eof error is an end of file error thrown when there is missing syntax, such as a ";" missing out of the end of a line of code. Without seeing your code it is difficult to tell you what the actual cause of your error. Check your code again and see if you left out any sort of braces parentheses or other similar syntax that is easily over looked.

Or post your source code so I may look at it

Comment: If the installer has not been deleted, one can run it again, or ask Windows to 'repair' an installation.  We definite need more info from Rishabh.